# How to draw a figure on a canvas in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, canvas

I'm still on the way to understand Python basics maybe my question is stupid:
How do I get a figure on a canvas (figure is a pyplot from matplotlib)?

Thank you, Reinhard

Sure I can save it via savefig and then place it as an Image on th canvas but this is somehow stupid ;-)

Comment: Could you please provide which library do you want to use to display the canvas? I mean Tkinter, or PyQt, or Kivy, or Matplotlib directly?

Comment: Matplotlb, like mentioned. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the plot in Tkinter, you can use this code:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Hello, world!")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8])
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas_widget = canvas.get_tk_widget()
canvas_widget.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Alternatively, to display a plot directly with matplotlib, you can use this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 6, 8])

plt.show()
```